# How to mock API request used inside function in a Django test?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I've got a little utility function built like this to grab data from another applications API:

```
# app/utils.py

import json

import requests
from django.conf import settings

def get_future_assignments(user_id):
    """gets a users future assignments list from the API

    Arguments:
        user_id {int} -- user_id for a User
    """
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    }
    api_app = settings.ASSIGNMENTS_API_ROOT_URL # http://project.org/appname/
    api_model = "futureassignments/"
    api_query = "?user_id=" + str(user_id)
    json_response = requests.get(
        api_app + api_model + api_query, headers=headers, verify=False
    )
    return json.loads(json_response.content)
```

It basically builds the API call and returns the response data - I'd like to test this.

```
# tests/test_utils.py

import mock
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from django.test import TestCase

from app.utils import get_future_assignments

class UtilsTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.futureassignments = [
            {
                "id": 342,
                "user_id": 18888,
                "job": 361,
                "location": "1234",
                "building": "Building One",
                "confirmed_at": None,
                "returning": None,
                "signature": None,
            },
            {
                "id": 342,
                "user_id": 18888,
                "job": 361,
                "location": "1235",
                "building": "Building Two",
                "confirmed_at": None,
                "returning": None,
                "signature": None,
            },
        ]

    @patch("app.utils.get_future_assignments")
    def test_get_future_assignments_with_multi_assignments(self, mock_gfa):
        """
        Test for getting future assignments for a user with mocked API
        """
        mock_gfa.return_value = Mock()
        # set the json response to what we're expecting
        mock_gfa.return_value.json.return_value = self.futureassignments
        assignments = get_future_assignments(18888)
        self.assertEqual(len(assignments), 2)
```

It keeps giving me an error that it can't reach the API to get a response (which is expected at the moment - since I'm running it locally and it cannot hit the API)

I'm new to using Mock - so maybe I'm way, way off base here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you want to mock API response, you should patch the `requests.get` function, **not** your own function which you want to test.

Comment: At present this test is a bit silly (even if you mock requests). Because you're testing setting headers you don't use and built-in json's ability to parse a mocked response.

Comment: So then Melvyn - how would you go about changing it? Being critical and providing no way to help better the situation or change things for the better is... not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you, I am also new to using `mock`. I believe it's intended to work like this:

```
    @patch("requests.get")
    def test_get_future_assignments_with_multi_assignments(self, mock_requests_get):
        """
        Test for getting future assignments for a user with mocked API
        """
        mock_requests_get.return_value = json.dumps(self.futureassignments)
        assignments = get_future_assignments(18888)
        self.assertEqual(len(assignments), 2)
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong!